# how do i display website comments above the last posted comment

Tags: html

hi on my website i've a comment box,
everytime i post a comment it get posted below the last comment
my question is: how do i place new comments on top of the old ones.

website: kru.run

This is my full code right now,

```html
<textarea id="title1" type="text " rows="1" cols="15" onkeyup="Allow()" placeholder="username"></textarea>
<textarea id="title" type="text " rows="3" cols="125" onkeyup="Allow()" placeholder="write a comment..."></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="insert()" style="width:50px;" /></form>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var titles = [];
    var titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
    var titleInput1 = document.getElementById("title1");
    var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

    function Allow() {
        if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && user.title.value != "") {
            user.title.value = "";
            alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
        }
        window.location.reload()
    }

    function insert() {
        titles.push(titleInput1.value + ": " + titleInput.value);
        clearAndShow();
    }

    function clearAndShow() {
        titleInput.value = "";
        messageBox.innerHTML = "";
        messageBox.innerHTML += " " + titles.join("<br/> ") + "<br/>";
    }
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

specifically
i think the insert function is the problem
what can i use instead of push?

```
function insert () {
    titles.push(titleInput1.value + ": " + titleInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `window.location.reload()` in your Allow function?

Comment: because i want the page to always reloaded from the server, ignoring the browser cache

Comment: But you're calling it in a function that is triggered with every keyup. Is that really what you want?

Comment: oh thats right, no i dont want that, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
function insert () {
titles.unshift(titleInput1.value + ": " + titleInput.value);
clearAndShow();
}
```

to insert as first item.